# in cocos2d can ccTouchesBegan be in a class not subclassed from ccLayer?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, cocos2d-iphone, touchesbegan, subclass

Hello I am making a side scrolling cocos2d game. I have one class subclassed from CCLayer and other classes subclassed from CCSprite and CCNode. Can I use the ccTouch methods in the classes subclassed from CCSprite and CCNode, or can they only be in the class subclassed from CCLayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

and call

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I used that and in the CCDirector line I am getting a warning saying sending class of incompatible type. Then when I run the app I press the screen for the touch and get a SIGABRT error.